# fancyhdr long section name overlaps page number

Tags: sectioning, header-footer, page-numbering, fancyhdr, books

Hi I use fancy header but the page number overlaps with the section name in the header. Is there a way to force either a tiny bit smaller text or just allow for longer margins in the header? Thanks.

MRE:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[LE]{\small\leftmark}%left on even
\fancyhead[RO]{\small\rightmark}%right on odd
\fancyhead[RE,LO]{ {\textbf{Page \thepage}} } %page number is right on even left on odd
\pagestyle{fancy}
\begin{document}
\chapter{Introduction}
\section{something}
Filler text
\subsection{something something}
Filler text
\newpage
\section{REALLY REALLY LONG TITLE OF SECTION}
\newpage
\section{REALLY REALLYy REALLY REALLY LONG TITLE OF SECTION}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You can use a shorter version of the section title as an optional  argument of `\section`.

Comment: sorry I really want/need the section title and the section number to be present.

Comment: In this case, the only simple solution I can see would be to use a smaller font size for the header.

Comment: @Bernard Is it possible to change the margin for just the header?

Comment: With `fancyhdr`, I'm not sure. With  `titleps` (a companion package of `titlesec`, you have a `\widenhead` command.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The normal way is to use `\section[short title for ToC and header]{Long title for main document}`.

```
\section[ABBREVIATED TITLE]{REALLY REALLY REALLY REALLY REALLY REALLY LONG TITLE OF SECTION}
```

I'm sure that you could abbreviate your title's text to fit in the header (and ToC); they are basically indicators to the full glory of the section title.

Answer (score 2):

This uses adjustbox to reduce the width only if needed.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[headheight=20pt]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\newlength{\markwidth}
\newcommand{\setmarkwidth}{\sbox0{\textbf{Page \thepage}}%
  \setlength{\markwidth}{\dimexpr\textwidth-\columnsep-\wd0}%
  \ifodd\value{page}
    \sbox1{\rightmark}%
    \ifdim\wd1<\markwidth \setlength{\markwidth}{\wd1}\fi
  \else
    \sbox1{\leftmark}%
    \ifdim\wd1<\markwidth \setlength{\markwidth}{\wd1}\fi
  \fi}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[LE]{\setmarkwidth\adjustbox{width=\markwidth}{\leftmark}}%left on even
\fancyhead[RO]{\setmarkwidth\adjustbox{width=\markwidth}{\rightmark}}%right on odd
\fancyhead[RE,LO]{ {\textbf{Page \thepage}} } %page number is right on even left on odd
\pagestyle{fancy}
\begin{document}
\chapter{Introduction}
\section{something}
Filler text
\subsection{something something}
Filler text
\newpage
\section{REALLY REALLY REALLY REALLY REALLY REALLY LONG TITLE OF SECTION}
\newpage
some text here
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can redefine these commands, wrapping the section titles in a custom-length box (or reducing the section titles font size):

```
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{\chaptername\ \thechapter . \parbox[t]{0.45\textwidth{\textit{#1}}}{}}}
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{\thesection.\ \parbox[t]{0.45\textwidth}{#1}}}
```

Answer (score 0):

You also can use a short title only in header, leaving the TOC entry and the section title in the main content untouched:

```
\section{Large title}
\sectionmark{Short title}
\label{sec:label}
```